# DefaultParsers : Cannot resolve symbol import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

Tags: scala, parsing, sbt

I would like to use DefaultParsers from Scala with idea. I would like to test to do this : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Parsing-Input.html

But my import doesn't work.

In my file.scala :

> import sbt._ import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

These two line doesn't work :
first line : sbt isn't known
second line : Cannot resolve symbol import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

In my build.sbt

> libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.scala-sbt"       %   "command"
>   % "0.13.1"

I think my build.sbt is not good (sbt update ok).

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sbt.complete` package is provided by the `org.scala-sbt % completion` JAR. So add this line to youd build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "completion" % "0.13.1"
```

For a full example of using SBT's completion library, see https://github.com/cjmx/cjmx.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my late answer.
I have tried to add your line but now : sbt update is success status but the problem is the same. Does "sbt update" is the only one command to lunch to get thie dependencie ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you.
Well, my software is compiling using sbt update compile from command line.
But now my problem is in Intellij. Idea says me that "import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers". I would like to use Intellij....
I don't understand. When I look in [project-name]-build.iml I found the jar path for sbt and the exists....